# How DSL query for match type is not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-dsl

Data set is below

```
PUT /dataall/test/1
{
    "name": "Computer Science 101",
    "room": "C12",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Gregg Payne",
        "department": "engineering",
        "facutly_type": "full-time",
        "email": "payneg@onuni.com"
        },
    "students_enrolled": 33,
    "course_publish_date": "2013-08-27",
    "course_description": "CS 101 is a first year computer science introduction teaching fundamental data structures and alogirthms using python. "
}

PUT /dataall/test/2
{
    "name": "Theatre 410",
    "room": "T18",
    "professor": {
        "name": "Greg",
        "department": "art",
        "facutly_type": "part-time",
        "email": ""
        },
    "students_enrolled": 47,
    "course_publish_date": "2013-01-27",
    "course_description": "Tht 410 is an advanced elective course disecting the various plays written by shakespere during the 16th century"
}
```

DSL query is below

```
GET dataall/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
          "professor.name":"Greg"
}
  }
}
```

mapping  is below. Professor is in nested json

```
{
  "dataall" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "course_description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "course_publish_date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "dataproduct" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "professor" : {
          "properties" : {
            "department" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "email" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "facutly_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "room" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "students_enrolled" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected out is 2(because "Greg" is similar to Gregg Payne) but i am getting one that is second document only which is exact match?

Why my query is not working? Even is it mandatory to match_phrase_prefix.

My other index are working fine, is it because of mapping nested json?

Comment: What is the mapping?

Comment: @Gibbs added the mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since you have not provided mapping of your data, there can be two possibilities that either your `professor` field is of nested data type OR Object data type**

Considering you have created **nested data type** for `professor` field.
To know more about Match Phrase prefix query refer to this  [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "room": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "professor": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "nested":{  
      "path":"professor",
      "query":{  
        "match_phrase_prefix":{  
          "professor.name":"Greg"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, considering the document contains an **inner object** `professor`. To know more about Object data type refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html)

**Mapping:**

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": { 
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "professor": { 
        "properties": {
          "name":  { "type": "text" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Search query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "professor.name": "Greg"
    }
  }
}
```

**The above search returns documents that contain phrases beginning with `Greg` in the `name` field of `professor`. To know more about Match phrase prefix query you can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)**

Comment: what is the us of match_phrase_prefix. I have added the mapping also

Comment: @aysh since you have not specified any mapping for the document you are using, ES will generate default dynamic mapping based on the data you index (same as mapping which u have mentioned in your question), so you can go with the second search query which I have mentioned in the question. It will give you the desired search result :)

Comment: @aysh to know about how Match prefix query you can refer this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html , I have also updated my answer that gives a brief of how the search query returns result. Please go through that

Comment: @ESCoder if we have the field as object and don't specify the individual fields for example: {"professor" : { "type" : "object"}}. -- without specifying individual fields like first name/last name, will we be able to search for the first/last name.  I couldn't search it using just object at the highest level

Comment: @profcalculus if you have defined `professor` as of `object` type, then you will be able to search `first name/last name` if they are inner objects of the `professor` field

Comment: Thanks @ESCoder but if we have type as object without specifying first name or last name the search using match was not working.  the search would look something like this ->  "query" : { "match" : { "professor" : "Greg"  } } , this didnt work though